# Reset specific ion-tab to main view every time I enter on it

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

So I have the following tabs:

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab tabsHideOnSubPages="true" [root]="NewsView"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabsHideOnSubPages="true" [root]="SituationView"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabsHideOnSubPages="true" [root]="RankingsView" ></ion- tab>
    <ion-tab tabsHideOnSubPages="true" [root]="EmailsView"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabsHideOnSubPages="true" [root]="MenuView"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

As you can see the last one is a menu page.
In there, in order to keep the menu visible on each of the first pages in the menu, I navigate using .setRoot(Page), so I am overwriting the contents of the MenuPage

Basically what I have is:

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list class="menu">
        <button ion-item detail-none text-end (click)="goToSchedule()">
            Agenda
        </button>
        <button ion-item detail-none text-end (click)="goToFilesList()">
            Files
        </button>
        <button ion-item detail-none text-end (click)=“goToHelpPage()”>
            Help
        </button>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

And inside the .ts:

```
goToSchedule() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(SchedulePage);
}
```

When I move from MenuPage tab to a different tab, then come back to MenuPage tab, instead of seeing the menu, I see the last sub-page I was on (like Files / Schedule)

How can I reset the page to the MenuPage view each time I enter this tab?

Thank you

Comment: Could you create a stackblitz for this, at least I am having trouble understanding what this is about, or rather what `In there, in order to keep the menu visible on each of the first pages in the menu` means.

Comment: @AJT_82 - as you can see, on each tab I have tabsHideOnSubPages="true". This means that if instead of .setRoot(SchedulePage) I use .push(SchedulePage), I loose the bottom tabs on that page. By using .setRoot, I will also see the tabs on ScheldulePage, FilesPage, HelpPage (main view)

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean, thanks for explaining for this stupid one :D